# Use helm-company as default for company autocompletion?

Tags: helm, completion, company-mode

I want [helm-company](https://github.com/yasuyk/helm-company) as the default selection method for company. Helm-company is meant to be invoked manually after company completion started. But I would really like to invoke helm automatically on completion (after `.` etc) instead of using the usual pop-up method company provides.

I tried to use `company-completion-started-hook` but it did not work. I'm not very familiar with company, has anyone solved a similar problem or knows how to accomplish this?

Comment: For that you'd need to write a company frontend using Helm.  I've actually attempted to do such a thing, but gave up once I realized that Helm sucks for this task because first, it pops up at a completely different place than where you are completing (makes for an annoying distance your eyes have to travel) and second, the keys to navigate Helm are completely different from what you'd typically go for for completion.  In other words, the impedance mismatch is too great.

Comment: @wasamasa and anyone else interested in this functionality. Using ivy you can now have completion with regex search with inline overlay using [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/57fnar/ivy_completion_at_point_in_an_overlay/)